# Database disappears in emulator

Tags: java, sqlite

MainActivity Code

```
package kz.talipovsn.database;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int LARGE_FONT = 16; // Размер шрифта для режима крупного шрифта
    private final int SMALL_FONT = 12; // Размер шрифта для режима обычного шрифта
    private int fontSize = SMALL_FONT; // Выбранный размер шрифта

    MySQLite db = new MySQLite(this); // Класс работы с нашей базой данных

    EditText editText; // Компонент для задания строки поиска
    TextView textView; // Компонент для вывода ответа
    CheckBox checkBox1;
    CheckBox checkBox2;
    CheckBox checkBox3;
    CheckBox checkBox4;
    CheckBox checkBox5;
    CheckBox checkBox6;

    static final String FILTER = "FILTER"; // Имя параметра для сохранения при переворачивании экрана
    String filter = ""; // Фильтр поиска

    SharedPreferences sPref; // Класс для работы с настройками программы
    static final String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "Config"; // Имя файла настроек приложения
    static final String FONT_SIZE = "FontSize"; // Имя параметра для сохранения размера шрифта в настройках приложения

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Сохранение данных при перевороте экрана
        savedInstanceState.putString(FILTER, filter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Активация меню
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Доступ к компонентам
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        checkBox1 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBox3 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        checkBox4 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        checkBox5 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        checkBox6 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);

        textView.setKeyListener(null); // Запрет на изменение данных с клавиатуры

        // Чтение сохраненной настройки размера шрифта из параметров приложения
        sPref = getSharedPreferences(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fontSize = sPref.getInt(FONT_SIZE, SMALL_FONT);

        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize); // Установка начально размера шрифта
        textView.requestFocus(); // Передача фокуса на комонент чтобы закрылось окно ввода у "editText"

        // Восстановление фильтра после переворота экрана
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(FILTER));
        }

        textView.setText(R.string.Загрузка_данных);

        // Обработчик изменения текста в компоненте "editText"
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // Сделаем поиск данных в другом потоке
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        filter = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String data = db.getData(filter, checkBox1.isChecked(), checkBox2.isChecked(), checkBox3.isChecked(), checkBox4.isChecked(), checkBox5.isChecked(), checkBox6.isChecked());
                        // Сделаем вывод результата синхронно с основным потоком
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                textView.setText(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            }

        });

        // Инициализация начального поиска (показать все записи)
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                editText.setText(filter);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Установка правильного отображения пункта выбора крупного шрифта
        menu.findItem(R.id.large_font).setChecked(fontSize == LARGE_FONT);
        return true;
    }

    // Обработчик выбора пунктов меню
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        // Написать автору
        if (id == R.id.email) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getString(R.string.myemail)});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Добавьте_еще_номер));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.Предлагаю_такой_номер));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.Посылка_письма)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.Нет_установленного_почтового_клиента, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
        // Установка/снятие крупного шрифта
        if (id == R.id.large_font) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            int size = item.isChecked() ? LARGE_FONT : SMALL_FONT;
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
            fontSize = size;
            return true;
        }
        // Выход
        if (id == R.id.exit) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Метод при закрытии окна
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Сохранение размера шрифта в настройках программы
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(FONT_SIZE, fontSize);
        ed.apply();
    }
}
```

..................................................
Here is the MySQLite code, for working with the database, it does not show errors in the code. Possible errors with the emulator version. With one filter PRICE worked...................................

`MySQLite Code`

```
    package kz.talipovsn.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MySQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3; // НОМЕР ВЕРСИИ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ И ТАБЛИЦ !

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "phones"; // Имя базы данных

    static final String TABLE_NAME = "emergency_service";
    static final String ID = "id";
    static final String NAME = "name";
    static final String PRICE = "price";
    static final String TYPE = "type";
    static final String POWER = "power";
    static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    static final String COUNTRY = "country";

    static final String ASSETS_FILE_NAME = "telephone.txt"; // Имя файла из ресурсов с данными для БД
    static final String DATA_SEPARATOR = "|"; // Разделитель данных в файле ресурсов с телефонами

    private Context context; // Контекст приложения

    public MySQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Метод создания базы данных и таблиц в ней
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + PRICE + " INTEGER,"
                + TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + POWER + " INTEGER,"
                + WEIGHT + " INTEGER,"
                + COUNTRY + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        System.out.println(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        loadDataFromAsset(context, ASSETS_FILE_NAME,  db);
    }

    // Метод при обновлении структуры базы данных и/или таблиц в ней
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        System.out.println("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Добавление нового контакта в БД
    public void addData(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, int price, String type, int power, int weight, String country) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, name);
        values.put(PRICE, price);
        values.put(TYPE, type);
        values.put(POWER, power);
        values.put(WEIGHT, weight);
        values.put(COUNTRY, country);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    // Добавление записей в базу данных из файла ресурсов
    public void loadDataFromAsset(Context context, String fileName, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            // Открываем поток для работы с файлом с исходными данными
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
            // Открываем буфер обмена для потока работы с файлом с исходными данными
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { // Читаем строку из файла
                String strTrim = str.trim(); // Убираем у строки пробелы с концов
                if (!strTrim.equals("")) { // Если строка не пустая, то
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strTrim, DATA_SEPARATOR); // Нарезаем ее на части
                    String name = st.nextToken().trim(); // Извлекаем из строки название организации без пробелов на концах
                    int price = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
                    String type = st.nextToken().trim();
                    int power = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
                    int weight = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
                    String country = st.nextToken().trim();
                    addData(db, name, price, type, power, weight, country);
                }
            }

        // Обработчики ошибок
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public String getData(String filter, boolean isName, boolean isCountry, boolean isPrice, boolean isWeight, boolean isPower, boolean isType) {

        String selectQuery; // Переменная для SQL-запроса

        if (filter.equals("")) {
            selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + NAME;
        } else {
            if (isName) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + NAME + filter + ") ORDER BY " + NAME;
            } else if (isCountry) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + COUNTRY + filter + ") ORDER BY " + COUNTRY;
            } else if (isPrice) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + PRICE + " >= " + filter + ") ORDER BY " + PRICE;
            } else if (isWeight) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + WEIGHT + filter + ") ORDER BY " + WEIGHT;
            } else if (isPower) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + POWER + filter + ") ORDER BY " + POWER;
            } else if (isType) {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + TYPE + filter + ") ORDER BY " + TYPE;
            } else {
                selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + TYPE + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " + POWER + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'"
                        + " OR " + WEIGHT + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " + COUNTRY +
                        " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " + NAME + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + ") ORDER BY " + NAME;
            }
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Доступ к БД
        try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); // Выполнение SQL-запроса

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(); // Переменная для формирования данных из запроса

        int num = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // Если есть хоть одна запись, то
            do { // Цикл по всем записям результата запроса
                int n = cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME);
                int t = cursor.getColumnIndex(PRICE);
                int k = cursor.getColumnIndex(TYPE);
                int s = cursor.getColumnIndex(POWER);
                int a = cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHT);
                int d = cursor.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY);
                String name = cursor.getString(n); // Чтение названия организации
                int price = cursor.getInt(t); // Чтение телефонного номера
                String type = cursor.getString(k);
                String power = cursor.getString(s);
                String weight = cursor.getString(a);
                String country = cursor.getString(d);
                data.append(String.valueOf(++num) + ") " + name + ": " + price + ": " + type + ": " + power + ": " + weight + ": " + country + ": " + "\n");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); // Цикл пока есть следующая запись
        }

        return data.toString(); // Возвращение результата
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

}
```

```
    The errors themselves
12/08 20:52:48: Launching 'TSN_DEMO_06_Database' on Pixel 2 API 22.
Install successfully finished in 7 s 497 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "kz.talipovsn.database/kz.talipovsn.database.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3903 on device 'Pixel_2_API_22 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.066ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1193(84KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 3MB/3MB, paused 5.853ms total 64.414ms
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 39 (6695563-x86_64) (code 300008)
I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 0 ms (timestamps 7557-7557)
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {15b25306}
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful, fd=31 off=46184 len=3037
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:32 off:229484 len:1089587
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb17cd03c50, tid 3903
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fb17ccf88e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb17ccf88e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fb17cd07e80)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/Atlas: Validating map...
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb1863fb550, tid 3946
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fb17cd4cca0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb17cd4cca0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fb17cdd5600)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb17cd4cca0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fb17cdd5600)
I/System.out: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emergency_service
I/System.out: CREATE TABLE emergency_service(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,price INTEGER,type TEXT,power INTEGER,weight INTEGER,country TEXT)
```

Tried to completely reinstall the database